# How to filter a list of files based on naming convention (prefix)

Tags: string, powershell

I have a long list of files with a similar naming convention. My goal is to have Powershell pull in a list of files with the same prefix. I'm new to the language and unsure how to go about this. Any advice / ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service nor a forum, but a site for programmers helping collegues who got stuck with a distinct problem. Own research and code attempts (even unsuccesful) presented in a [mcve] are expected, accompanied by actual and expected results.

Comment: A [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) with your prefix and an attached [wildcard/Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1) should get you going.

Comment: What properties if the files should be output in _the list_? Do you need that on screen or as a csv file for instance?